# Connect to MySQL on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, mysql

The connection worked fine the other day and for some reason is doesn't. MySQL is running in Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I am trying to connect to a database using ODBC Connector 5.1 from Windows 7.

I have tried commenting out and keeping the bind-address in the `cnf` file. I have tried to grant all access. I have been reading endless amounts of tutorials and posting to attempt to figure it out. I cannot figure out what is going on, also I am a newbie to all this and I have noticed that most posting leave out some minor things that others may be attuned to.

Help!  Thanks in advance.

The service is running and I get the following from netstat -tlpen | grep mysql:

```
tcp  0  0.0.0.0.0:3306  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  106  15172  3565/mysqld
```

I get the following from netstat -tlpen:

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      106        15172       3565/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          7092        776/smbd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8325        784/rpcbind     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9759        1325/perl       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44819           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9584        -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8809        947/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          7090        776/smbd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9000        -               
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          7088        776/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          8328        784/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8811        947/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          7085        776/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          9003        -               
tcp6       0      0 :::47906                :::*                    LISTEN      0          9586        -
```

iptable -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

[image]

Comment: Without any further info, that would be hard to answer. You need to tell us the output of `netstat -tlpen`, the one of `iptables -L` and what is the error message you get when trying to establish the ODBC connection. That will be a good start already, further info would probably still be needed!

Comment: I added to my original question with the things you mentioned.

Comment: So from a network point of view, it looks alright. Now it is about the user accounts, how did you configure the user account you are using for the ODBC connection? Or about security policies, have you check if you are using AppArmor? Check if you have something **denied** as reported by AppArmor in either audit.log, syslog or messages (files that you can find under /var/log)

Comment: AppArmor is not installed from what I can tell. I followed the white paper developed by the program that I am trying to connect. It is accessible from http://www.landfx.com/documentation/doku.php?id=land_f_x_mysql_install_on_linux. I commented out the bind address in my.cnf, I have also tried it with 0.0.0.0 and the servers ip.

Comment: Could you tell us the exact error message ODBC Connector is returning **and** could you activate the logs in MySQL and see if it reports any error while connecting? You can check this answer how to configure MySQL logging: http://serverfault.com/a/253688/67419

Comment: You are never going to believe this, but the static ip address that I thought I set for the server didn't stick and on restart the server picked up a different ip address. The original tutorial/posting on defining a static ip address didn't mention removing  dhcp-client.

Comment: I an glad you solved your problem. I would create an answer where you would state that you need to disable dhcp-client (you could even state how), and then accept the answer, so other can find quickly how to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. It turns out that the static ip that I set for my server was not completely establishedand upon reboot another computer on my LAN grabbed the ip address that I dictated for the server.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and changed the information similar to this t[utorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/), using the information realted to my LAN.

Instead of changing the resolv.conf file as the tutorial states I added:

```
dns-nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX
dns-nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX
```

as two additional lines at the bottom of the interfaces file. XX.XX.XX.XX are replaced with the dns-nameservers that I identified from my router. Other information that I read indicates that you could use others, i.e. Google or OpenDNS. Once that was done and the network was restarted, I had to remove dhcp-client from the server. Without doing this the static ip address does not maintain upon restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've checked everything that can be wrong with MySQL. The next thing I would check is to see if MySQL is still running and listening on the correct port.

`service mysql status`

If it is note running, start it:

`service mysql start`

After that, I would make sure it's still listening on the default port by running

`netstat -tlpen | grep mysql`

The default port for MySQL is 3306 so it should return something like this:

`tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  107  8073  790/mysqld`

Comment: Note: if netstat reports that it is listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 then MySQL Server is bound to the local interface only and cannot be used via the network.